# Most effective similarity measure for list-ranked items

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

We're trying to find similarity between items (and later users) where the items are ranked in various lists by users (think Rob, Barry and Dick in [Hi Fidelity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146882/)).  A lower index in a given list implies a higher rating.

I suppose a standard approach would be to use the Pearson correlation and then invert the indexes in some way.

However, as I understand it, the aim of the Pearson correlation is to compensate for differences between users who typically rate things higher or lower but have a similar relative ratings.

It seems to me that if the lists are continuous (although of arbitrary length) it's not an issue that the ratings implied from the position will be skewed in this way.

I suppose in this case a Euclidean based similarity would suffice.  Is this the case?  Would using the Pearson correlation have  a negative effect and find correlation that isn't appropriate?  What similarity measure might best suit this data?

Additionally while we want position in the list to have effect we don't want to penalise rankings that are too far apart.  Two users both featuring an item in a list with very differing ranking should still be considered similar.

Answer (score 3):

[Jaccard Similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) looks better in your case. To include the rank you mentioned, you can take a bag-of-items approach.

Using your example of (`Rob`, `Barry`, `Dick`) with their rating being (3,2,1) respectively, you insert `Rob` 3 times into this user `a`'s bag.

```
Rob, Rob, Rob.
```

Then for `Barry`, you do it twice. The current bag looks like below,

```
Rob, Rob, Rob, Barry, Barry.
```

You put `Dick` into the bag finally.

```
Rob, Rob, Rob, Barry, Barry, Dick
```

Suppose another user `b` has a bag of `[Dick, Dick, Barry]`, you calculate the Jaccard Similarity as below:

- The intersection between `a` and `b` = `[Dick, Barry]`
- The union of `a` and `b` = `[Rob, Rob, Rob, Barry, Barry, Dick, Dick]`
- The Jaccard Similarity = 2/7,

that is, the number of items in the intersection divided by the number of items in the union.

This similarity measure does **NOT** penalize rankings that are far apart. You can see that:

> Two users both featuring an item in a list with very differing ranking should still be considered similar.

Answer (score 2):

The most well-known similarity metric based only on ranking is [Spearman's correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient). It just assigns "1" to the first item, "2" to the second and so on and computes a (Pearson) correlation coefficient. (You can make the values descending too, which is more intuitive -- won't matter to Pearson's correlation.)

Spearman's correlation is implemented in the project, but, that said I do not think it is very useful.

[Tau rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient) is a more principled measure of how much ranked lists match, but it's not implemented. It would not be hard.

Comment: I'm intrigued by Tau rank.  It does seem perfect but I'm concerned about the complexity of it. Because you have to compare all the possible pairing of items there's a lot more work to do per user pair. Perhaps it would suffer in denser data sets?

Comment: Considering only items in each user's top ratings, or randomly sampling a modest number of pairs, should give a reasonable approximation quickly. I have no hands-on experience with this metric, just my guesses here.